# can I have operations outside a function body in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int val = 100;
//cout<<val<<endl;    //this is not valid.
int main(){
int val=100;  //why this is valid?
return 0;
}
```

I found out these two things in the above code:

- `cout<<val<<endl;` is not valid outside the main function body. Why is that?
- I think the two `val`s are all defined in the `namespace std`. But how come they are both valid?

Comment: WRT your second question, are you saying that you wanted to modify a variable called `val` which is defined somewhere in `namespace std` or are you saying that you defined those variables in `namespace std`?

Comment: NEITHER `val` is in the `std` namespace.  The 1st `val` is in the global namespace, which also happens to have access to members of the `std` namespace. The 2nd `val` is local to `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `cout<<val<<endl;` is not valid outside the main function body. Why is that?

Because the standard says that expression statements can only be in block scope.

> can I have operations outside a function body in c++?

You can't have expression statements outside a function.

However, declaration statements can have sub-expressions that have side-effects such as `cout<<val<<endl` (note the lack of semicolon) in which case those expressions will be executed during initialisation of whatever was declared. Neil Butterworth shows an example of this in their answer.

> 2. I think the two vals are all defined in the namespace std

You think wrong. Neither is declared in the `std` namespace.

One `val` is declared in the global namespace, while the other is declared in the function scope. Declaring one variable in a nested scope within potential  scope of another vairable with the same name is called shadowing i.e. `val` in the block scope shadows `val` in the namespace scope.

> ```
> void main()
> ```

This is also not valid. `main` must return `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialise things, possibly via function calls, so you could say something like:

```
   ostream & os = cout<< 42 <<endl;
```

but the utility of this is not obvious, and you would possibly run into problems with the order of instantiation of objects like `cout`.

What you cannot do is write code such as:

```
  x = x + 1;
  for ( int y = 0; y < 10; y++ ) {}
```

outside of a function - that's the way the language is defined.

And in your code neither `val` is in the `std` namespace, and it would be illegal to try to place them there. You need to read up on scope.